# jQuery selector for child of sibling without providing the context or using traversing functions

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm working with a jquery plugin that requires me to identify certain buttons with a string it uses as a selector but it doesn't allow me to provide the selector's context or use traversing functions.

If I have:

```
<div>
    <div id="dialog"></div>
    <div>
        <button><span>back</span></button>
        <button><span>next</span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the time I need to provide the selector all I know is the id of the dialog (in this case, "#dialog").

This selector correctly selects the "next" button:

```
$("button:contains('next')", "#dialog ~ div")
```

Can that selector be rewritten without the context argument? I tried this but it doesn't return any elements:

```
$("#dialog ~ div button:contains('next')")
```

I'm assuming that is looking for buttons that are siblings instead of buttons within siblings which is why it's failing.

Comment: could you add a class to each of your buttons, then use `$("#dialog + div button.next")`?

Comment: That's very strange. It *should* work. It *is* looking for `button`s within `div` siblings of `#dialog`.

Comment: @joeshmo I'm not directly creating the buttons; they're being created by another plugin. I could try adding a class to the buttons after they're created. The "+" next adjacent selector also won't work for me in practice; it turns out there are 8 divs in between my div#dialog and the div with the buttons.

Comment: do you have a working example of the plugin in action?

Comment: @Joseph it's the [JQuery Form Wizard](http://thecodemine.org/). I think the issue is with the selector itself though.

Comment: @BoltClock you're right; it should work. The issue is related to a bug in the selector engine. I added an answer to this question with the relevant info and will update this again when it gets fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to your buttons and use that in the selector.  For example, change your markup to:

```
<div>
    <div id="dialog"></div>
    <div>
        <button class='back'><span>back</span></button>
        <button class='next'><span>next</span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then this selector should work:

```
$("#dialog ~ div button.next")
```

<strike>`~` would work too, but `+` is more specific.</strike> (edit, not acutally right after the div like in the example)

I think the problem is that the button does not contain `next`, it contains `<span>next</span>`. Using `:contains('<span>next</next>')` instead of `.next` seems to select the `span`, not the `button`.

Comment: Adding a class on the button does work with your selector, thanks. I tried removing the span inside the button and using my original "contains" selector but it still doesn't work. I'll use your solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

the only other way i know is

```
$("#dialog").find("button:contains('next')")
```

Comment: That does not really help here. It is not one selector.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this? http://jsfiddle.net/Wd4zF/

```
$('#dialog').next().children('button span:last');
```

Comment: I can't in this case. The plugin I'm using just allows me to pass in a selector; it handles doing the selection.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is a bug in the Sizzle selector engine used by jQuery. I've created [ticket 9939](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9939) for it and submitted a [patch](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/pull/70) to fix it.